# LDA vectors coefficient interpretation

Tags: vector, lda

I am trying to interpret/quantify the coefficients of the vectors obtained after an `LDA`.

Let's say that I obtain an eigenvector (unitary)/Score for a two classes LDA, such as:

```
0.1348
0.2697
0.4045
0.5394
0.6742
```

the last dimension is the most important in the ability to discriminate, right ? But can I quantify it as `0.6742^2  /1=0.4545 %`, meaning that this dimension contributes to 45% of the discrimination "power"/ability?

Or `0.6742/2.0226=0.3333` contributing to `33%` of the discrimination "power"/ability?

Or neither of those are right and how to quantify it if possible.
I am sorry if this is trivial, but I couldn't find a clear answer yet on the internet.

Thank you,

Tual

Answer (score 0):

Let's see a small example using iris data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

#load iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

#create and fit the model
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
lda.fit(X,y)

#get the eigenvectors. The expected shape is [number of features, number of classes - 1]
lda.scalings_
```

---

**Results**

```
array([[-0.81926852,  0.03285975],
       [-1.5478732 ,  2.15471106],
       [ 2.18494056, -0.93024679],
       [ 2.85385002,  2.8060046 ]])
```

---

As expected, we have 4 rows and 2 columns. now, **the first column is the first linear discriminant**. The values that you see e.g. -0.8192 correspond to the **influence of the corresponding feature on the corresponding linear discriminant** (-0.8192 corresponds to the LD1).

So, the higher the absolute value, the higher the influence of the feature on the LD.

---

***In more depth***: in the first row we have: [-0.81926852,  0.03285975]. This means that the influence of the first feature (sepal length (cm) in our case) on the first LD (LD1) is higher compared to the influence of the same feature on the second LD (LD2).

Hope this helps.